# Nesting routes along with redux integration not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'am nesting routes in my project. I have App.js in which I have defined the routes and inside the component I have more routes which I want them to be nested. The only problem is that my nested route is in the component which is connected to redux. The nested routing is not working properly.

I have already tried it from the official documentation but it does not work.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy

App.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function HowItWorks() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 style={{ margin: 20 }}>How It Works</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function AboutUs() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 style={{ margin: 20 }}>About Us</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <div>
            <Route path="/" exact component={HowItWorks} />
            <Route path="/howitworks" exact component={HowItWorks} />
            <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={AdminContainer} />
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my Redux Container file which gets called based on the route specified in App.js. Also my App.js file may get connected to redux in the future by the connect() method.

AdminContainer.js

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import MainDesktopComponent from "../components/Admin/MainDesktopComponent";

const mapStateToProps = state => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {};
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MainDesktopComponent);
```

MainDesktopComponent.js

I have tried this i.e giving the nested route inside Switch and many different ways but it is not working. Also note that I also want to pass props to the Dashboard component which will come from the above redux container component through mapstatetoprops.

```
import React from "react";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Switch } from "react-router";

function MainDesktopComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/admin/dashboard"
          render={props => {
            <Dashboard/>;
          }}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainDesktopComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but what about try this?

```
<Switch>
      <Route
          exact
          path="/admin/dashboard"
          render={cProps => <Dashboard {...cProps} {...props} />}
      />
</Switch>
```

return Route render component.

Comment: I tried this. But the route is only not working. When I go to the route i.e admin/dashboard then it does not load the component. I saw in react dev tools. Please help!

Comment: @SourabhKarmarkar I wish this gonna helps you. https://codesandbox.io/s/2jv7mj69yy

Comment: @Thanks man!! It works perfectly. I had not put in the SWITCH!!